# How can I get this output in C++ visual studio?

Tags: c++, string, oop, visual-c++, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hi. My name is blank. " << endl;
    cout << "my hobby is";
    cout << "my pet's name is" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

> Hi. My name is blank. My hobby is. My pet's name is.

What I need it to look like is, on three separate lines:

> Hi. My name is blank.
>   my hobby is.
>   my pet name is.

Comment: I need "hi my name is...", "my hobby is", and "my pet's name is" on 3 SEPERATE line

Comment: Why can't you use `<< endl;` on the second line like you do on the first and third?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Output]

I guess this gives you the answer you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << " Hi. My name is blank";
    cout << "\n my hobby is";
    cout << "\n my pet's name is" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the \n? We didn't learn about this in class we only used end1. I can't figure it out.

Comment: We did use cin though. is there a way to do this using cin?

Comment: @AmyLee `cin` is for input only. `cout` is for output only. `std::endl` writes a `'\n'` and then flushes the output. `cout << " Hi. My name is blank" << endl; cout << "my hobby is" << endl; cout << "my pet's name is" << endl;` Works fine for everyone.